# ¿Como agregar texto a un link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Existe un sitio donde descargo archivos .torrent, este sitio contiene una descripción detallada del archivo '.torrent' a descargar.. pero el archivo descargado tiene otro nombre! tipo: 4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC.torrent  (un hash)

Un día descubrí que colocando, al final del link: **?title=** mas el titulo que *quiera, se descarga con *ese título y no con el otro, q no es descriptivo.

Entonces se me ocurre agregarle -al link que proporciona el sitio- **?title=** + el nombre que da el sitio del contenido a descargar, quiero mostrarles el `HTML` del sitio:

```
    <div class="col-9 page-content">
      <div class="box-info torrent-detail-page  vpn-info-wrap">
        <div class="box-info-heading clearfix"><h1> The Ranch (2016) Season 03 S03 (1080p NF WEB-DL x265 HEVC 10bit A... </h1>

        </div>
        <div class="box-info-detail no-top-radius">
          <div class="torrent-category-detail clearfix">
            <ul class="download-links-dontblock btn-wrap-list">
              <li><a class="fbccddae btn btn-bcdfdaac" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC&dn=The+Ranch+%282016%29+Season+03+S03+%281080p+NF+WEB-DL+x265+HEVC+10bit+AAC+5.1+Joy%29+%5BUTR%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2F9.rarbg.com%3A2710%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2F9.rarbg.to%3A2710%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.torrent.eu.org%3A451%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.tiny-vps.com%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.si%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.zer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fp4p.arenabg.com%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.internetwarriors.net%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.zer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fcoppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce" onclick="javascript: count(this);"><span class="icon"><i class="flaticon-magnet"></i></span>Magnet Download</a> </li>
                            <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="fbccddae btn btn-bcfdfcfb" onclick="javascript: count(this);" href="#"><span class="icon"><i class="flaticon-two-down-arrows"></i></span>Torrent Download</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                    <li><a class="fbccddae btn btn-acddcbca" target="_blank" href="http://itorrents.org/torrent/4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC.torrent"><span class="icon"><i class="flaticon-torrent-download"></i></span>ITORRENTS MIRROR</a> </li>
                    <li><a class="fbccddae btn btn-acddcbca" target="_blank" href="http://torrage.info/torrent.php?h=4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC"><span class="icon"><i class="flaticon-torrent-download"></i></span>TORRAGE MIRROR</a></li>
                    <li><a class="fbccddae btn btn-acddcbca" target="_blank" href="http://btcache.me/torrent/4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC"><span class="icon"><i class="flaticon-torrent-download"></i></span>BTCACHE MIRROR</a></li>
                    <li><a class="fbccddae btn btn-bcdfdaac" href="magnet:?xt=urn:btih:4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC&dn=The+Ranch+%282016%29+Season+03+S03+%281080p+NF+WEB-DL+x265+HEVC+10bit+AAC+5.1+Joy%29+%5BUTR%5D&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2F9.rarbg.com%3A2710%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2F9.rarbg.to%3A2710%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.torrent.eu.org%3A451%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fexodus.desync.com%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.tiny-vps.com%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fopen.demonii.si%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.zer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fp4p.arenabg.com%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.internetwarriors.net%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.zer0day.to%3A1337%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.leechers-paradise.org%3A6969%2Fannounce&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Fcoppersurfer.tk%3A6969%2Fannounce"><span class="icon"><i class="flaticon-magnet"></i></span>None Working? Use Magnet</a></li>
                  </ul>              
              </li>
                                          <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li><a id="fbafedff" class="fbccddae btn btn-fbafedff" href="/st-rd-The Ranch (2016) Season 03 S03 (1080p NF WEB-DL x265 HEVC 10bit AAC 5.1 Joy) [UTR]" ><span class="icon"><i class="flaticon-stream"></i></span>Play No&zwnj;w (Str&zwnj;eam)</a></li>
                                                        <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>
              <li><a id="cabccbac" class="fbccddae btn btn-cabccbac" href="/v-pn2dl-The Ranch (2016) Season 03 S03 (1080p NF WEB-DL x265 HEVC 10bit AAC 5.1 Joy) [UTR]"><span class="icon"><i class="flaticon-shield-sat"></i></span>An&zwnj;on&zwnj;ymous Download</a> </li>
                            <li style="margin-top:0px;"></li>

                            ---
<div class="manage-box">

            <div class="infohash-box">
              <p> <strong>Infohash :</strong> <span>4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC</span></p>
            </div>
          </div>
```

La parte que me interesa es: `href="http://itorrents.org/torrent/4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC.torrent"`
La idea es tomar `http://itorrents.org/torrent/` + el hash + ?title= + su descripcion..
quedando así: `href="http://itorrents.org/torrent/4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC.torrent?title=The Ranch (2016) Season 03 S03 (1080p NF WEB-DL x265 HEVC 10bit AAC 5.1 Joy) [UTR]"` al dar clic en ese enlace, el archivo descargado tendrá el nuevo titulo

Estaba trabajando en un script que tomaba el link por `.class` como..

```
$('a.btn-fbafedff').attr('href', function(i, a){ return a + "?title=" });
```

*Mientras buscaba la forma de agregarle el id de la descripción*, pero ese sitio tiene las clases dinámicas (si, es muy mal sitio) ademas como notarán la descripción no la coloca completa: `<h1> The Ranch (2016) Season 03 S03 (1080p NF WEB-DL x265 HEVC 10bit A... </h1>` por lo que tendría que sacarla de `<li><a id="fbafedff" class="fbccddae btn btn-fbafedff" href="/st-rd-The Ranch (2016) Season 03 S03 (1080p NF WEB-DL x265 HEVC 10bit AAC 5.1 Joy) [UTR]" >` quitando `/st-rd-` (además me temo que lamentablemente esas `class` también serían dinámicas) :/

En fin, necesito ayuda ya que no tengo ningún `script` que solucione el problema. La secuencia sería así:

- El `script` toma para editar `http://itorrents.org/torrent/`
- Agrega el hash (podría usar `<span>` de `class="infohash-box"`)
- A ese hash le agrega **.torrent?title=**
- Y finalmente agrega la descripción.. que de ultima la toma de
  `class="box-info-heading clearfix"`

Ejemplo de como está por defecto:
[http://itorrents.org/torrent/4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC.torrent](http://itorrents.org/torrent/4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC.torrent))

Ejemplo de como debería quedar:
[http://itorrents.org/torrent/4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC.torrent?title=The%20Ranch%20(2016)%20Season%2003%20S03%20(1080p%20NF%20WEB-DL%20x265%20HEVC%2010bit%20AAC%205.1%20Joy)%20[UTR]](http://itorrents.org/torrent/4413BDA923946ADDE1EBDC40BCA70C26083E36EC.torrent?title=The%20Ranch%20(2016)%20Season%2003%20S03%20(1080p%20NF%20WEB-DL%20x265%20HEVC%2010bit%20AAC%205.1%20Joy)%20[UTR]))

- *El último con descripción tiene codificación para poder mostrarse
  correctamente de ejemplo aquí*

Ojalá alguien pueda ayudarme saludos a todos y gracias por leer, sus comentarios y soluciones (ojalá jaj), sería un `script` para tampermonkey

Comment: Por qué no simplemente tomas el url completo y le agregas `"title?=" + titulo` ?

Comment: porque necesito que se aplique a todos las url que proporciona el sitio, actualmente tengo que abrir en sesiones de 20 pestañas, descargar el archivo, y manualmente renombrar cada archivo previamente identificado abriendolo, para después cerrar la pestaña y continuar. Sino tengo cientos de archivos con solo numeros por nombres, y si luego me interesa alguno en particular tengo q abrir uno por uno hasta dar con el correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes probar con algo así, no sé si es lo que pretendías o te he entendido mal, con lo que sea me comentas y lo modifico:

```
var tituloHeader = $('body').children('.box-info-heading.clearfix:eq(0)').html();
var url = "http://itorrents.org/torrent/";
var hash = $('body').find('.infohash-box:eq(0)').find('span').html();
var resultado = url + hash + ".torrent?title=" + tituloHeader;
var conteo = $('body').find('li > a.btn').length;
for(var i = 0;i <= conteo;i++){
        var elemento = $('body').find('li > a.btn:eq("'+ i +'")');
        var contenido = elemento.text();
            if(contenido == "An‌on‌ymous Download"){
                elemento.attr('href',resultado);
            }
        };
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudar, es genial la idea de ponerlo en Play No‌w (Str‌eam) como lo hiciste, queda bien hasta `.torrent?title=` luego de eso me sale **undefined** es como si `tituloHeader` no estaría tomando bien el titulo, amigo

Comment: amigo modifiqué un poco la primera línea: `var tituloHeader = $('body').find('h1:eq(0)').html();` y ahí lo toma bien, de nuevo te agradezco tu ayuda fundamental, ahora veo como hago para agregarle a `.btn-fbafedff` el atributo `target="_blank"` y quedaría genial. Lamentablemente `.btn-fbafedff` es dinámico ya q en realidad ese es un botón de publi entonces es muy cambiante :/ ojalá sean pocos los q tengas jaja para poder cubrirlos a todos. **Doy como resuelta esta pregunta aunque no me molestaria una mejora, sobre todo para tratar de evitar la clase boluble `.btn-fbafedff`**

Comment: *tengaN :D (puse mal, ahí corrijo)

Comment: muchas gracias compi!! me acabo de fijar y no te lo tmoa bien por que se me ha olvidado poner un `.` en antes de `box-info-heading` por lo que no lo encuentra

Comment: en realidad tampoco lo tomada así  no se xq. Amigo esa maldita `class` `btn-fbafedff`. me está matando se cambia al igual q su ID  ¿se podría usar el texto `</span>` como referencia? como? o se podría crear un botón asignarle un ID, un class y usar ese?

Comment: el contenido del `span` es estatico?? me refiero,siempre va a aparecer esos 3 links?y en cual de ellos te gustaria cambiarle las propiedades?

Comment: no, los link cambian. estaba viendo y el unico q no cambia es el boton **An‌on‌ymous Download** (el texto spam)

Comment: entonces el link que me dices la id no cambia?? no es dinamica??compruebamelo porfa

Comment: si cambia, fijate es d aca https://x1337x.ws/torrent/3511738/The-Ranch-2016-Season-03-S03-1080p-NF-WEB-DL-x265-HEVC-10bit-AAC-5-1-Joy-UTR/

Comment: Buenas,tienes la edicion corregida con lo que quieres.Además he corregido la variable `tituloHeader`.Recorro El DOM para llegar al elemento que contenga el texto `An‌on‌ymous Download` para que le agregue la referencia

Comment: uh de reputisima madre amigo, quedó super! muchisimas gracias por toda la ayuda. esa solución es perfecta, no se como lo haces pero gracias 