# Cómo extraer el texto delante de un link?

Tags: html, enlace

Antes pasaba valores através de link en html así **(en la página1)**:

```
<a href="https://miweb.com/pagina?valor=mi-valor-texto>
```

Ahora estoy intento pasar el valor directamente:

```
<a href="https://miweb.com/pagina/mi-valor-texto>
```

El problema es que luego no sé cómo puedo introducir `mi-valor-texto` en una variable **(en la página2)**

Quiero conseguir que mis enlaces se vean de esta manera: `https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/228590/como-agregar-texto-a-un-link`. Con el texto alfinal. Supongo que sirve como **id** de la pregunta.
Si no me explico bien, porfavor háganme saber para que replantee mi duda. Gracias.

**JS** (página2):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function(){
      var valor;

      if (window.location.hash) {
        valor= window.location.hash;
    }

  });
```

No me devuelve ningún valor.

Comment: Ya corregí las etiquetas. No pretendía ponerlas enteras. Bueno, he intentado recuperar el valor con JS: Lo añado al final de la pregunta. No me devuelve ningún valor.

Comment: Creo que estoy entendiendo un poco, al decir que lo quieres poner en una variable ¿Es una variable por parte del servidor?

Comment: Sí. Sería un id en mi base de datos. De modo que en lugar de ``enlace?id=mi-texto``, sea ``enlace/mi-texto``. Como indiqué antes

Comment: Ok, ya entiendo. ¿Qué usas para el servidor? ¿Node o PHP?

Comment: Uso PHP. Para manejar variables y las query

Comment: Ya lo tenías implementado desde PHP con `?valor=mi-valor-texto`? Si es así, publicá ese código.

Comment: Ya lo hice con ``?valor=mi-valor-texto``  y lugo lo recibo como  `` $valor= $_GET["valor"]`` . Lo que deseo es  ``/mi-valor-texto`` . Para evitar mostras en el link **valor=** . Pero no sé cómo recibirlo.

Comment: Lo que buscas se llama [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php) en PHP. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras ... Muchas gracias broth!!! Con eso he logrado lo que deseaba!!! No esperaba que fuera tan fácil. Bendito **parse_url** jejeje... GRACIAS!